# Power adapter green light blinking on - non genuine adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, display

I recently acquired a new power adapter 85W for my macbook pro retina late 2013. I made sure the specifications matched the official Apple adapter and in fact I have not noticed any performance issues.

The problem is the green light on the magnet connector is sometimes blinking. I am wondering if that could could cause any damage to my battery or have some other issues. Otherwise it charges properly and battery duration is normal.

This is the product by the way: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Magnetic-Charger-MacBook-Retina-Display/dp/B00BJ97CWU

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A blinking LED is not a signal that the original MagSafe Power Adapter would output, so it's hard to say why it does that, perhaps contact the manufacturer. But it sounds like there's something wrong with the adapter.

It is technically possible that a faulty power supply hurts your battery or even your machine (as in logic board, etc.). I have experienced several MacBooks that have been bricked by 3rd party batteries in my time as an Apple Technician.